# Can't get pins on molex micro-fit 3.0 connector

Tags: pcb, connector

I have this molex connector:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0430251800/531407

and these pins:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B072KTD2ZJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072KTD2ZJ)

With 22awg wire. I have followed this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCU86Yxnnac

And I cannot get the pin to click into the connector like the guy in the video does. The pin doesn't slide in all the way despite my applying considerable force (which doesn't seem necessary)

I've never made a molex connector before so I'm completely lost as to what I am doing wrong here.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Every day millions of crimped terminals are pushed into the plastic housing of connectors by workers.

That means that crimped terminals are supposed to enter easily in the body of the black Molex housing and make a little sound or click that your hand should feel.

Are you using the right crimping tool?

The right crimp terminal PN for that housing is: 0430300010
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0430300010/252480

Are you 100% sure you purchased crimp terminal 0430300010 from Amazon?

Comment: Indeed - the Amazon listing for the contacts linked from the OP advertises them as being for the Mini-Fit Jr series, which is not the same as Micro-Fit 3. Amazon is not a typically a great place to buy electronic piece parts anyway - no supply chain quality control, high likelihood of fake or mislabeled parts.